# Как организовать динамическое создание массивов?

Tags: c#, массивы, динамические-массивы

Я открываю файл, считываю число, которое говорит о том, сколько массивов мы будем использовать. Число будет все время меняться, поэтому заранее объявить определенное количество массивов не получится.

Answer (score 3):

```
//Тут получили количество элементов и записали его в Count
int[][] myArrays;
myArrays = new int[Count][];
for (int i=0;i<Count;++i) 
{
  myArrays[i] = new int[CountElements];
  for (int j=0; j<CountElements; ++j)
    myArrays[i][j] = element; //Заполняем массив
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте контейнеры. Тут есть два пути:

1) мы знаем длину нашего будущего масива, пусть это будет 5 элементов

```
//создаем заранее не известное количество массивов int
List<int[]> arrays = new List<int[]>();
//каким то образом получили количество наших масивов, допустим их будет 4
int count = 4;
//заполняем(или выполняем любые другие операции)
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
   arrays.Add(new int[5]);
   for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
   {
      arrays[i][j] = j + i;
   }
}
```

2) Вариант когда мы на перед не знаем колличество элементов в наших масивах

```
//создаем заранее не известное количество массивов int    
List<List<int>> arrays = new List<List<int>>();
//каким то образом получили количество наших масивов, допустим их будет 4            
int count = 4;
//заполняем(или выполняем любые другие операции)
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    arrays.Add(new List<int>());
    //каким то образом получили количество элементов текущего масива, в нашем случае i + 4 (для наглядности).
    int length = i + 4;
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
       arrays[i].Add(j + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое - создайте массив массивов, и инициализируйте в нем столько массивов сколько вам нужно.